# Confused about the definition of "Exact Algorithm"

Tags: algorithm, optimization, logic

What does it mean by saying "an algorithm is exact" in terms of Optimization and/or Computer Science? I need a precisely logical/epistemological definition.

Comment: Context needed. Show us where exactly that term is used.

Comment: In general an optimal solution can not be acquired in reasonable time. A approximate solution, however, might be within reach. So there are approximation and exact algorithms.

Comment: An exact algorithm finds the solution to the problem asked. This is by contrast with an approximate algorithm, which only gets close to the solution. As others explain, there are practical situations such that exact algorithms cannot be used and one must content oneself with approximations.

Answer (score 7):

`Exact` and `approximate` algorithms are methods for solving optimization problems.

`Exact algorithms` are algorithms that always find the optimal solution to a given optimization problem.

However, in combinatorial problems or total optimization problems, conventional methods are usually not effective enough, especially when the problem search area is large and complex. Among other methods we can use heuristics to solve that problems. Heuristics tend to give suboptimal solutions. A subset of heuristics are `approximation algorithms`.

When we use `approximation algorithms` we can prove a bound on the ratio between the optimal solution and the solution produced by the algorithm.

E.g. In some `NP-hard` problems there are some `polynomial-time` approximation algorithms while the best known exact algorithms need `exponential time`.

For example while there is a `polynomial-time` approximation algorithm for `Vertex Cover`, the best `exact algorithm` (using memoization) runs in  **[O(1.1889<sup>n</sup>) pp 62-63](https://books.google.gr/books?id=d-UFCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)**.

Answer (score 4):

The term *exact* is usually used to mean "the opposite of *approximate*".  An approximation algorithm finds a solution to a slight variation of an optimzation problem that admits soltions that are "close" to the optimum in some sense, but nonetheless are desirable.  As @Sirko said in the comments, the approximation is usually of interest because the exact problem is intractable or undecidable, where the approximate version is not.  Often, more than one kind of approximation may be of interest.

Here are examples:

1. An exact algorithm for the Traveling Salesman problem is NP Complete. The TSP is to find a route of minimum length L for visiting each of N cities on a map.  NP Completeness says the best known algorithms still need time that is an exponential function of N.  An approximation algorithm for TSP finds a route of length no more than cL for some fixed c > 1.  For example, you can easily construct the minimum spanning tree of the cities in time that is a polynomial in N and walk around the tree, covering each edge twice, to obtain an approximatoin algorithm for the case c = 2.  The implied goal is to find algorithms for constants c as close to one as possible.
2. An exact algorithm for compiling a program that produces correct results in minimum time from any given source code is - under reasonable assumptions - undecidable.  Yet of course we use "optimizing compilers" every day that improve the speed of code with no promise of true optimality.

Comment: Aren't your examples a little "high level" ?

Comment: @Gene This a good idea that defining _Exact_ by contrasting it with _Approximation_ concept. The definition is too dependent on the latter.

Comment: @Moh_NA_X  My friend, it's not my idea. It's the conventional usage.  See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm , but there are thousands of papers in the theory of algorithms that use "exact" and "approximate" in the same way.

Comment: @Gene: an OP asking for a definition of an exact algorithm has little chance of knowing of NP completeness.

Comment: Note that deriving a 2-approximation using an MST only works for the metric TSP, where the edge weights all obey the triangle inequality. There is no constant-factor approximation (that runs in polynomial time) for the general TSP.

Answer (score 3):

In optimization, there are two kinds of algorithms. **Exact** and **approximate** algorithms.

Exact algorithms can find the optimum solution with precision.

Approximate algorithms can find a *near optimum* solution.

The main difference is that exact algorithms apply in "easy" problems.
What makes a problem "easy" is that it can be solved in reasonable time and the computation time doesn't scale up exponentially if the problem gets bigger. This class of problems is known as **P**(Deterministic Polynomial Time). Problems of this class are used to be optimized using exact algorithms.
For every other class of problems approximate algorithms are preferred.